# <p> tag text color changed failed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I dont understand why I am not been able to change the color of the text '`Welcome`'. Following are the two approaches, any help would be appreciated.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script language="text/javascript">
            function changeColor(c) {
                message.style.color=c;
            }
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p id="message" style="color:orange"> Welcome </p>
         <ul id="color">
             <li onclick='changeColor(this.innerText);'>Blue</li>
             <li onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Red</li>
          </ul>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're relying on a couple of things there I would recommend not relying on:

1. `message` being a global because you've given it as an `id` value. Instead, use `document.getElementById` to look up the element.
2. `innerText` is mostly a Microsoft thing. With your example as shown, you could use `innerHTML`, which is reliable cross-browser, but I'd recommend storing the color in a `data-` attribute instead so your label can be whatever you want it to be (including being a different language than the CSS color names).

Here's how I'd probably approach it without introducing any libraries and keeping things fairly simple:

Markup:

```
<p id="message" style="color:orange"> Welcome </p>
<ul id="color">
<li data-color="blue">Blue</li>
<li data-color="red">Red</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('color'),
      list = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
      message = document.getElementById('message'),
      index;
  for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].onclick = changeColor;
  }

  function changeColor() {
    message.style.color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  }
})();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ituwex)

The `script` tag containing the JavaScript must be *after* the markup in order to work correctly.

That relies solely on standards and should be compliant with all major browsers. The `data-` attributes are invalid in HTML4 (if validation is part of your workflow), but they work fine with all major (and probably all minor) browsers. They are valid as of HTML5 (which allows any attribute with the prefix `data-` on any element, for exactly this purpose).

---

**Update**: Re your comment below:

> How to change the changeColor function so tht it accepts changeColor(this.innerText);'? Or changeColor(this.style.color); ??

If you're looking to separate out the functionality (perfectly reasonable), you'd do this:

```
(function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('color'),
      list = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
      message = document.getElementById('message'),
      index;
  for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].onclick = changeColorViaDataAttr;
  }

  function changeColorViaDataAttr() {
    changeColor(this.getAttribute('data-color'));
  }

  function changeColor(color) {
    message.style.color = color;
  }
})();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ituwex/4)

Since the functions only change the color of the `message` element, actually probably best to rename those functions slightly, but you get the idea.

---

**Off-topic**: A lot of this stuff can be a lot easier if you leverage the hard work done by people who've created libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Those libraries help smooth over browser differences and provide a lot of utility functionality. For instance, the way I've hooked up the event handlers above (assigning to the `onclick` property), like your `onclick` attributes, is *very* old-fashioned, but the more up-to-date way varies a bit because of older Microsoft browsers and so would have complicated the example a fair bit. Libraries smooth over that sort of thing for you.

Here's that same JavaScript code using jQuery:

```
(function() {
  $("#color li").click(changeColor);

  function changeColor() {
    $("#message").css("color", this.getAttribute("data-color"));
  }
})();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ituwex/2)

Although you could make it even more compact if you like:

```
(function() {
  $("#color li").click(function() {
    $("#message").css("color", $(this).data("color"));
  });
})();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ituwex/3)

Comment: How to change the changeColor function so tht it accepts changeColor(this.innerText);'? Or changeColor(this.style.color); ??

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's because `message` is an undefined variable. What you need to do is this:

```
function changeColor(c) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<li onclick='changeColor(this.innerText);'>Blue</li>` does not work, because function `changeColor` expects the color as an argument, not the text.

`<li onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Red</li>` does not work, because the variable `message` in the body of `changeColor` is not defined.

At least the second error you could have caught yourself if you had looked into the error console of your browser.

Comment: How to change the changeColor function so tht it accepts changeColor(this.innerText);'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an element using it's ID, you need to do this: document.getElementById("message")

So, like this:

```
<script type="javascript">

function changeColor(c)
{
     document.getElementById("message").style.color=c;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to your `changeColor` function should be the colour that you want to display. In the function you need to actually get a reference to the DOM object you intend to manipulate, using:

`document.getElementById("message").style.color = c;`

In your example, `message` is an undefined global variable, so replace that with a reference to the required DOM element and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `script tag` you have `language=` which should be `type=`
2. You should use `document.getElementById("message")` instead of `message`.
3. You should feed the function with an actual color. The `string text "Blue"` is not a color

   ```
   function changeColor(c)
   {
      document.getElementById("message").style.color = c;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to do

```
<li style="color:Red" onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Red</li>
```

instead of

```
<li onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Red</li>



<html> 
        <head>
            <script language="text/javascript">
                function changeColor(c) {
                    message.style.color=c;
                }
            </script>
         </head>
         <body>
             <p id="message" style="color:orange"> Welcome </p>
             <ul id="color">
              <li style="color:Red" onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Red</li>
               <li style="color:Blue" onclick='changeColor(this.style.color);'>Blue</li>
              </ul>
         </body>
    </html>
```